# Run through Adjacency matrix with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, image-segmentation, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to implement a adjacency matrix with pointers like such:

```
int **Adj_Matrix;

int** create_Mat_adj(int lines, int columns)
{
    int **Adj_Matrix = new int*[lines]; 
    int *Adj_Matrix_block = new int[lines * columns+1]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < columns+1; ++i, Adj_Matrix_block += columns+1 ) {
         Adj_Matrix[0]= new int; // sink or source for img segmentation
         Adj_Matrix[i] = Adj_Matrix_block;
   }
    return Adj_Matrix;
}

void delete_Mat_adj(int **i)
{
   delete [] i[0];
   delete [] i;
}
```

I'm using this to solve a image segmentation problem, using Edmond's Karp and a BFS, as such I am adding +1 to the Matrix size as a source / sink for the algorithm. I runninbg though that matrix starting at the +1 position to fill the vertical and horizontal link values from input one by one.

When running through the matrix to fill the blocks with the weights of the links I am running into a segmentation fault error:

```
  //add horizontal links to adj matrix
  int w = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < columns-1; j++){
      //get horizontal links individually from input
      cin>>aux;
      Adj_Matrix[w][w+1] = aux;
      Adj_Matrix[w+1][w] = aux;
      w++;
    }
    w++;
  }
  //add vertical links to adj Matrix
  int k = 1;
  w=columns+1;
  for (int i = 0; i < lines-1; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
      //get vertical links individually from input
      cin>>aux;
      Adj_Matrix[k][w] = aux;
      Adj_Matrix[w][k] = aux;
      w++;
      k++;
    }
  }
```

I had the algorithm working but I changed implementation from a `vector< vector<int> >`  for the Adj_Matrix to using pointers because I was running into memory problems when computing huge matrixes (>800x800).

Comment: Try clang sanitizers.

Comment: There wasn't really a need to use pointers just because `std::vector<std::vector>` used memory.  You could have just used `std::vector<int>` and allocate both rows and columns in a single vector, and then compute the `(x, y)` point of the vector by using simple arithmetic.

Comment: _"I was running into memory problems when computing huge matrixes (>800x800)."_. What kind of memory problems? Do you have a computer with 1 MB of RAM? Did you call `std::vector::reserve()`?